# Change font style for specific entry in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, bold, tocloft

Is there a way to specify a different font style for one specific entry in the TOC using `tocloft` or otherwise? For example, is it possible to bold just the first section:

**Section 1 ..... 1**  <-- only bold first section

Section 2 ...... 2

Section 3 ...... 4

Section 4 ...... 7

I know `\cftsecfont` and `\cftsecpagefont` can specify the general fonts, but how about just for one specific entry?

Basically, in my preamble I have something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\GillSans\fontsize{14pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\GillSans\fontsize{14pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont}
```

If I add bolding, it bolds everything:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries\GillSans\fontsize{14pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries\GillSans\fontsize{14pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont}
```

My document just contains:

```
\tableofcontents
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch Updated my post. I'm basically just trying to customize the outputs of `\tableofcontents`. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonDispa Accepted! Thanks again~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\styledsection` command will first suppress the normal styled section from the ToC and then replace the entry with the styled version with a bold section number, section title, and section page number.

Choose the font style using the command `\fontstyle`.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}% add dots 

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontsize{14pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontsize{14pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont}

%*************************************************************** added
\newcommand{\fontstyle}{\bfseries} % choose the font style <<<<
    
\newcommand{\styledsection}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}% suppress this section in ToC     
\section{#1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}% allow and add the styled entry of section in ToC 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\protect\fontstyle\numberline{\thesection}#1}{\protect\fontstyle\the\value{page}}}       
}
%*************************************************************** 

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents    
    \newpage
    \styledsection{Section 1}   %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \newpage
    \section{Section 2}
    \newpage
    \section{Section 3}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried it out and it works great. I guess I left out a detail that I'm actually compiling the PDF from an Rmd, and for some reason I'm getting an error when trying to knit the Rmd. It works when I compile it directly as a .tex file tho so looks like the issue is the Rmd file...

Maybe this is the wrong forum to post R issues, but here's the error if anyone has any idea?

`! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.`
`<inserted text>`
                `\par` 
`l.5 \contentsline`
                  `{section}{\numberline {2}Section 2}{2}{section.2}`

Comment: Nevermind! I just replaced `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\protect\fontstyle\numberline{\thesection}#1}{\protect\fontstyle\the\value{page}}}` with `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bfseries#1}` and think it works. Thanks again :)